# Фильт по значениям в django-admin

Tags: python, django-admin, django

У меня есть 2 модели:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

и

```
class Discount(models.Model):
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
```

В django-admin если создавать/редактировать конкретный экземпляр *Discount*, поле выбора Клиента представляет из себя длинный-длинный список, по которому очень неудобно искать. Как бы сделать этот список поудобнее, желательно с функцией ввода текста, который являлся бы фильтром по данному полю, т.е. имени клиента?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)

> `raw_id_fields` is a list of fields you would like to change into an Input widget for either a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField